# How to write series of Do[ ]'s with a single Table[ ]?

Tags: functions, programming, syntax, functional-style

Edited to provide more information (sorry I don't know how to format matrices here)

I would like to replace:
    m = 4;

```
mult[i_, j_] := mult[i, j] = (tstar[Abs[i - j]] + tstar[i + j - 2])/2
Do[pmult[j] = Sum[a[i - 1]*mult[i, j], {i, 1, m}], {j, 1, m}]; 
Do[pmult[j] = Expand[pmult[j]], {j, 1, m}]; 
Do[c[j] = {}, {j, 1, m}]; 
Do[Do[c[j] = Append[c[j], Coefficient[pmult[j], tstar[i], 1]], {i, 0, 
    m - 1}], {j, 1, m}]; 
q = Transpose[Table[c[i], {i, 1, m}]]
```

with a single `Table` function (I believe this is possible). I attempted

```
mult[i_, j_] := mult[i, j] = (tstar[Abs[i - j]] + tstar[i + j - 2])/2
pmult[j_] := pmult[j] = Sum[a[i - 1]*mult[i, j], {i, 1, m}]; 
q = Table[
  Coefficient[Expand[pmult[j]], {j, 1, m}, tstar[i], 1], {j, 1, m}]
```

but I receive the error message

```
Coefficient::nonopt: Options expected (instead of 1) beyond position 3 in Coefficient[a(0) tstar(0)+a(1) tstar(1)+a(2) tstar(2)+a(3) tstar(3),1,tstar(i),1]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules. >>
```

The output should be

```
(a(0)   a(1)/2  a(2)/2  a(3)/2
a(1)    a(0)+a(2)/2 a(1)/2+a(3)/2   a(2)/2
a(2)    a(1)/2+a(3)/2   a(0)    a(1)/2
a(3)    a(2)/2  a(1)/2  a(0))
```

Can someone please shed some light on what I've done incorrectly? (i and j are indices) Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `{j,1,m}` in `Coefficient[Expand[pmult[j]], {j, 1, m}, tstar[i], 1]`?

Comment: Sorry, m=4 (arbitrary), and j is an indices.

Comment: Could you give a clean example of the input and output that you want?  This will be easier than dissecting your `Do` loops and `Append`s etc.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The only input is the value m (mxm matrix is generated). I am having trouble dissecting it, also. This was written by someone else, and I am trying to write it in a simple, easier to understand, manner. The output will be an mxm matrix in terms of a[ ]'s. Sorry I don't know how to format outputs.

Comment: Okay, so `q` is the single output you are interested in, correct?

Comment: Yes, which is an mxm matrix in terms of the variable "a". It works as is, but I'm trying to write it cleanly and eliminate as many recursive tasks as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please examine this and determine if it is giving the result that you desire:

```
m = 3;

mem : mult[i_, j_] := mem = (tstar[Abs[i - j]] + tstar[i + j - 2])/2

ptab = Table[Expand @ Sum[a[i - 1]*mult[i, j], {i, m}], {j, m}]

Table[Coefficient[j, tstar[i - 1], 1], {j, ptab}, {i, m}] // Transpose
```

If you include the definitions of `a` and `tstar` I may be able to simplify this further.

Comment: That's perfect! That cut my computation time by over half. I have rules to substitute in values for a and tstar later, so symbolic is how I need it at this point. Thanks so much!

Comment: @gKirkland Okay, I'm glad I could help, and thanks for the Accept.